# Move product price next to quantity of add to cart button

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'd like move the Product price to the left of the quantity minus button on the add to cart module.

I'll be adding more attributes to use as variables such as size, color and material and would like the price to remain unaffected as I do so.

I'm willing to change size of the button and size of price font if there isn't enough space.

Link : https://www.evertrendi.co.za/index.php/product/red-square-handbag/
[desired new location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/np90r.png)

Attempted to use a plugin but it broke the website.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a child theme in Wordpress. In the child theme, create a content-"single-product.php" file.
In this file you can change the appearance of the product page as you want.

Comment: I do have child theme on a staging site I made to solve the problem. It's the code I'm struggling with. I tried to make an add action but it didn't work. Tried a css code, it also didn't work.